# CSS Transpose the HTML (Rows to Columns)

Tags: html, css, rows, transpose

How do I transpose HTML rows to columns?

I found several ways, but failed to keep proper order in the table.

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```css
#t01 {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow
}
```

```html
<table id="t01">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>MultipleChoice : </th>
      <th>FreeTextQuestin:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Option_1</td>
      <td>my answer</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It looks like this:
[CurrentStyle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o19F.jpg)

And I would like to have like this:
[mainTarget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPJVC.jpg)

The number of rows is dynamic and I would love to use only CSS.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know this might be an obvious question, but this seems like an XY-Problem to me. Why can't you generate the correct row/column markup in HTML?

Comment: The HTML part is coming from the other systems that can not be adjusted,  for the sake of future steps in the process,  this part should be manipulated by the automated flows that's why looking for the manipulation way within the CSS

Comment: If you are processing the document anyways, why not parse the HTML properly and restructure?

Comment: @Polygnome, nice idea, I have applied and worked properly but still curious about CSS that I have no experience on it, but thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is several answers to your question, you can either use the [css grid property](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/grid)

or you can just do :

```
<table id="t01">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>MultipleChoice : </th>
            <td>Option_1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>FreeTextQuestin: </th>
            <td>My answer </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The number of rows is dynamic and the CSS part would be the part of main process, there is no way to change it manually due to fact of source system

Comment: then go with a css grid and change the flow direction